# Java XML DOM: how are id Attributes special?

Tags: java, dom

The javadoc for the `Document` class has the following note under `getElementById`.

> Note: Attributes with the name "ID" or "id" are not of type ID unless so defined

So, I read an XHTML doc into the DOM (using Xerces 2.9.1).

The doc has a plain old `<p id='fribble'>` in it.

I call `getElementById("fribble")`, and it returns null.

I use XPath to get "//*[id='fribble']", and all is well.

So, the question is, what causes the `DocumentBuilder` to actually mark ID attributes as 'so defined?'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the `getElementById()` call to work, the `Document` has to know the types of its nodes, and the target node must be of the XML ID type for the method to find it.  It knows about the types of its elements via an associated schema.  If the schema is not set, or does not declare the `id` attribute to be of the XML ID type, `getElementById()` will never find it.

My guess is that your document doesn't know the `p` element's `id` attribute is of the XML ID type (is it?).  You can navigate to the node in the DOM using `getChildNodes()` and other DOM-traversal functions, and try calling `Attr.isId()` on the id attribute to tell for sure.

From the [getElementById](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29) javadoc:

> The DOM implementation is expected to
>   use the attribute Attr.isId to
>   determine if an attribute is of type
>   ID.
>
> **Note: Attributes with the name "ID" or
>   "id" are not of type ID unless so
>   defined.**

If you are using a `DocumentBuilder` to parse your XML into a DOM, be sure to call [`setSchema(schema)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setSchema%28javax.xml.validation.Schema%29) on the DocumentBuilderFactory before calling newDocumentBuilder(), to ensure that the builder you get from the factory is aware of element types.

Answer (score 51):

These attributes are special because of their **type** and not because of their **name**.

**IDs in XML**

Although it is easy to think of attributes as `name="value"` with the value is being a simple string, that is not the full story -- there is also an **attribute type** associated with attributes.

This is easy to appreciate when there is an XML Schema involved, since XML Schema supports datatypes for both XML elements and XML attributes. The XML attributes are defined to be of a simple type (e.g. xs:string, xs:integer, xs:dateTime, xs:anyURI). The attributes being discussed here are defined with the `xs:ID`  built-in datatype (see [section 3.3.8 of the XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes](http://file:///Users/hoylen/Documents/Home/specifications/w3c/xml-schema/part2-datatypes/datatypes.html#ID)).

```
<xs:element name="foo">
  <xs:complexType>
   ...
   <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:ID"/>
   ...
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Although DTD don't support the rich datatypes in XML Schema, it does support a limited set of *attribute types* (which is defined in [section 3.3.1 of XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-attribute-types)). The attributes being discussed here are defined with an *attribute type* of `ID`.

```
<!ATTLIST foo  bar ID #IMPLIED>
```

With either the above XML Schema or DTD, the following element will be identified by the ID value of "xyz".

```
<foo bar="xyz"/>
```

Without knowing the XML Schema or DTD, there is no way to tell what is an ID and what is not:

- Attributes with the name of "id" do not necessarily have an *attribute type* of ID; and
- Attributes with names that are not "id" might have an *attribute type* of ID!

To improve this situation, the `xml:id` was subsequently invented (see [xml:id W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/)). This is an attribute that always has the same prefix and name, and is intended to be treated as an attribute with *attribute type* of ID. However, whether it does will depend on the parser being used is aware of `xml:id` or not. Since many parsers were initially written before `xml:id` was defined, it might not be supported.

**IDs in Java**

In Java, `getElementById()` finds elements by looking for attributes of **type** ID, not for attributes with the *name* of "id".

In the above example, `getElementById("xyz")` will return that `foo` element, even though the name of the attribute on it is not "id" (assuming the DOM knows that `bar` has an *attribute type* of ID).

So how does the DOM know what *attribute type* an attribute has? There are three ways:

1. Provide an XML Schema to the parser ([example](http://crumpling-rumblings.blogspot.com/2008/05/java-how-to-make-getelementbyid-work.html))
2. Provide a DTD to the parser
3. Explicitly indicate to the DOM that it is treated as an attribute type of ID.

The third option is done using the `setIdAttribute()` or `setIdAttributeNS()` or `setIdAttributeNode()` methods on the [`org.w3c.dom.Element` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html).

```
Document doc;
Element fooElem;

doc = ...; // load XML document instance
fooElem = ...; // locate the element node "foo" in doc

fooElem.setIdAttribute("bar", true); // without this, 'found' would be null

Element found = doc.getElementById("xyz");
```

This has to be done for each element node that has one of these type of attributes on them. There is no simple built-in method to make all occurrences of attributes with a given name  (e.g. "id") be of *attribute type* ID.

This third approach is only useful in situations where the code calling the `getElementById()` is separate from that creating the DOM.  If it was the same code, it already has found the element to set the ID attribute so it is unlikely to need to call `getElementById()`.

Also, be aware that those methods were not in the original DOM specification. The `getElementById` was introduced in [DOM level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/).

**IDs in XPath**

The XPath in the original question gave a result because it was only matching the attribute *name*.

To match on *attribute type* ID values, the XPath `id` function needs to be used (it is one of the [Node Set Functions from XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Node-Set-Functions)):

```
id("xyz")
```

If that had been used, the XPath would have given the same result as `getElementById()` (i.e. no match found).

**IDs in XML continued**

Two important features of ID should be highlighted.

Firstly, the values of all attributes of *attribute type* ID must be **unique to the whole XML document**.  In the following example, if `personId` and `companyId` both have *attribute type* of ID, it would be an error to add another company with `companyId` of id24601, because it will be a duplicate of an existing ID value. Even though the attribute names are different, it is the *attribute type* that matters.

```
<test1>
 <person personId="id24600">...</person>
 <person personId="id24601">...</person>
 <company companyId="id12345">...</company>
 <company companyId="id12346">...</company>
</test1>
```

Secondly, the **attributes are defined on elements** rather than the entire XML document. So attributes with the same attribute name on different elements might have different *attribute type* properties. In the following example XML document, if only `alpha/@bar` has an *attribute type* of ID (and no other attribute was), `getElementById("xyz")` will return an element, but `getElementById("abc")` will not (since `beta/@bar` is not of *attribute type* ID). Also, it is not an error for the attribute `gamma/@bar` to have the same value as `alpha/@bar`, that value is not considered in the uniqueness of IDs in the XML document because it is is not of *attribute type* ID.

```
<test2>
  <alpha bar="xyz"/>
  <beta bar="abc"/>
  <gamma bar="xyz"/>
</test2>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the schema example is dead by now.

Answer (score 4):

ID attribute isn't an attribute whose name is "ID", it's an attribute which is declared to be an ID attribute by a DTD or a schema. For example, the html 4 DTD describes it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 3):

The corresponding xpath expression would actually be `id('fribble')`, which should return the same result as `getElementById`. For this to work, the dtd or schema associated with your document has to declare the attribute as being of type ID.

If you are in control of the queried xml you could also try renaming the attribute to `xml:id` as per http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/.

Answer (score 2):

The following will allow you to get an element by id:

```
public static Element getElementById(Element rootElement, String id)
{
    try 
    {
        String path = String.format("//*[@id = '%1$s' or @Id = '%1$s' or @ID = '%1$s' or @iD = '%1$s' ]", id);
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate(path, rootElement, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        return (Element) nodes.item(0);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```