# JAVA XML, find recursively

Tags: java, xml

I need to find recursively xml Node by id in something like this:

```
<categories>
  <category id="1">
  </category>
  <category id="2">
     <category id="3"> 
     </category>
     <category id="4"> 
        <category id="5"> 
        </category> 
     </category>
  </category>
</categories>
```

I'm using DocBuilder.

I know that there is method `getElementById()`, but it doesn't work in my situation, where let's say, that I want to find an element with `id="5"`, when I am in the root node.

Is it possible ?

Comment: `getElementById()` searches the whole document, not just an element's child nodes. It should do what you want if you have a schema that specifies the attribute is a `xml:id`. (See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423430/java-xml-dom-how-are-id-attributes-special)

Answer (score 1):

Call the method with the root node:

```
Element element = getElementById(rootElement, "5");
```

And the recursive method:

```
public Element getElementById(Element element, String desiredId){
    if(desiredId.equals(element.getAttribute("id")))
        return element;
    for(int i=0; i < element.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){
        Node node = element.getChildNodes().item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            Element child = getElementById((Element) node, desiredId);
            if(child != null)
                return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: But this method is not full recursively... it won't goes deeper than first children...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like the following pseudocode

```
FindChild(parent, id)
{

    if(parent.getChildById(id)) return parent.getChildById(id);

    foreach(parent.child)
    {
         Element found = FindChild(child, id);
         if(found) return found;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

You'll have to decide what to do in case the element with the specified id appears in several places in the hierarchy (ie. return first occurence or build a list)