# XPath expression fails. (libxml2 in C)

Tags: c++, c, xpath, libxml2

I'm using libxml2 in a C program to do some stuff within XML documents.
Now... if I look to the following XPath I have an empty result.

```
/scheda_conservatore[1]/patrimonio_archivistico[1]/lower_list[@type='risorsa_informativa']/risorsa_informativa_nested[@id='037006-001-2012-ri002']
```

but... If I look for the following XPAth I have a non empty result containing elements that should have been matched even from the first one.

```
/scheda_conservatore[1]/patrimonio_archivistico[1]/lower_list/risorsa_informativa_nested[@id='037006-001-2012-ri002']
```

Now... if I check, step by step, my XPath I have...

```
/scheda_conservatore[1] -> Non empty node set
/scheda_conservatore[1]/patrimonio_archivistico[1] -> Non empty node set
/scheda_conservatore[1]/patrimonio_archivistico[1]/lower_list[@type='risorsa_informativa'] -> Empty Node set.
```

As I told before, the XML document DO contain a valid path but this is not matched by this request.
More: If I ask jEdit or other editors having XPath support to solve XPath expression for me, the result is a non empty node set.

I'm going mad. I watched the XPath expression thousands of times and there must be somethig very wrong at least as very hidden to my eyes even if it will surelly be brilliant to somebody else.

---

More...
The following, just asking for the 'type' attribute without looking at it's value, give a valid result. But the value is also correct.
/scheda_conservatore[1]/patrimonio_archivistico[1]/lower_list[@type]/risorsa_informativa_nested[@id='037006-001-2012-ri002']

---

Here's a "director's cut" of the larger XML document

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
  <scheda_conservatore    anno_rilevazione="2012" stato="non-storicizzata">  
     <!-- scheda 2012 per Bologna -->  
     <patrimonio_archivistico> 
        <lower_list type="complesso_archivistico"> 
           <complesso_archivistico_nested id="037006-001-2012-ca001" inventariazione="n"> 
              <lower_list type="altro_luogo_collocazione"> 
                 <altro_luogo_collocazione_nested id="037006-001-2012-alc001"> 
                    <!-- altro luogo 1 per bologna 2012 -->  
                    <upper_list type="complesso_archivistico"> 
                       <upper ref="ca002"/>  
                       <upper ref="ca003"/> 
                    </upper_list>  
                    <ubicazione>sotterraneo da botola segreta</ubicazione>  
                    <bridge_list type="sede"> 
                       <bridge ref="s001"/> 
                    </bridge_list>  
                 </altro_luogo_collocazione_nested>  
              </lower_list>  
              <!-- complesso 1 per bologna 2012 -->  
              <identificazione> 
                 <denominazione>Archivi dei Comprensori della provincia di Bologna</denominazione>  
                 <lista_altre_denominazioni> 
                    <!-- Modificato -->  
                    <altra_denominazione>Archivi dei Comprensori bolognesi</altra_denominazione>  
                    <altra_denominazione>Archivi dei Comprensori felsinei</altra_denominazione> 
                 </lista_altre_denominazioni>  
                 <livello>Complesso di fondi, Superfondo</livello> 
              </identificazione>  
              <dati_giuridici> 
                 <tipologia>Pubblico</tipologia>  
                 <notificato_dichiarato presente="y"> 
                    <data>20100304T000000</data> 
                 </notificato_dichiarato> 
              </dati_giuridici>  
              <lower_list type="titolare"> 
                 <titolare_nested id="037006-001-2012-t001"> 
                    <!-- titolare 1 per bologna 2012 -->  
                    <upper_list type="complesso_archivistico"> 
                       <upper ref="ca001"/>  
                       <upper ref="ca002"/> 
                    </upper_list>  
                 </titolare_nested> 
              </lower_list> 
           </complesso_archivistico_nested>  
        </lower_list>  
        <lower_list type="risorsa_informativa"> 
           <risorsa_informativa_nested id="037006-001-2012-ri001"> 
              <bridge_list type="complesso_archivistico"> 
                 <bridge ref="ca001"/>  
                 <bridge ref="ca002"/> 
              </bridge_list>  
              <!-- risorsa 1 per bologna 2012 -->  
              <descrizione> 
                 <autore>CSR - Centro studi e ricerche</autore>  
                 <titolo>Atti degli uffici: inventario-mappa topografica del...</titolo>  
                 <anno indicativo="y">1986</anno>  
                 <qualifica> 
                    <opz pubbl="y">Strumenti di ricerca archivistici</opz> 
                 </qualifica>  
                 <scelta_multipla nome="standard"> 
                    <opz valore="AACR2"/>  
                    <opz valore="Altro">EAD</opz> 
                 </scelta_multipla>  
                 <descr_estrinseca>Dattiloscritto (relativo a: documentazione post 1945 conservata in Viale Martiri della Libert&amp;#x2026;)</descr_estrinseca> 
              </descrizione>  
              <lista_pubblicazioni> 
                 <pubblicazione> 
                    <edita presente="y">stampa</edita>  
                    <edita_stampa> 
                       <curatore/>  
                       <edito_in/>  
                       <luogo/>  
                       <data/>  
                       <pagine/>  
                       <sbn/>  
                       <note/> 
                    </edita_stampa>  
                    <url/>  
                    <ultima_consultazione>20120611T165400</ultima_consultazione>  
                    <nota>Nessuna nota</nota> 
                 </pubblicazione>  
                 <pubblicazione> 
                    <edita presente="y">web</edita>  
                    <edita_stampa/>  
                    <url>www.risorsainformativa.gov</url>  
                    <ultima_consultazione/>  
                    <nota>Nessuna nota web</nota> 
                 </pubblicazione> 
              </lista_pubblicazioni>  
              <informatizzazione presente="y"> 
                 <scelta_multipla nome="applicativi_utilizzati"> 
                    <!-- MODIFICATO!! -->  
                    <opz valore="Access (database)"/>  
                    <opz valore="Altro">eXtraWay</opz> 
                 </scelta_multipla>  
                 <partecipazione_sistemi_informativi presente="y"> 
                    <descrizione>x.dams</descrizione> 
                 </partecipazione_sistemi_informativi> 
              </informatizzazione> 
           </risorsa_informativa_nested>  
        </lower_list>  
        <lower_list type="intervento"> 
           <intervento_nested autor_sovraintendenza="y" id="037006-001-2012-i001" in_corso="y"> 
              <!-- intervento 1 per bologna 2012 -->  
              <descrizione>Restauro archivi dei comprensori della provincia di Bologna</descrizione>  
              <scelta_multipla nome="tipologia"> 
                 <opz valore="Riordino"/>  
                 <opz valore="Altro">Pulizia</opz> 
              </scelta_multipla>  
              <avvio>20111101T000000</avvio>  
              <conclusione_prevista>20120701T000000</conclusione_prevista>  
              <conclusione_effettiva/>  
              <autore/>  
              <promotore/>  
              <scelta_multipla nome="standard_descrittivi"> 
                 <opz valore="ISAD"/>  
                 <opz valore="Altro">Descrizione altro standard descrittivo</opz> 
              </scelta_multipla>  
              <informatizzazione presente="y"> 
                 <scelta_multipla nome="applicativo_utilizzato"> 
                    <opz valore="Access (database)"/>  
                    <opz valore="Altro">eXtraWay</opz> 
                 </scelta_multipla>  
                 <partecipazione_sistemi_informativi presente="y"> 
                    <descrizione>x.dams</descrizione> 
                 </partecipazione_sistemi_informativi> 
              </informatizzazione>  
              <bridge_list type="complesso_archivistico"> 
                 <bridge ref="ca001"/> 
              </bridge_list> 
           </intervento_nested>  
        </lower_list>  
        <note/> 
     </patrimonio_archivistico>  
     <note/>
     <?xw-meta Dbms="ExtraWay" DbmsVer="24.3.1" OrgNam="3D Informatica" OrgVer="1.0" Classif="1.0" ManGest="3.1" ManTec="0.0.4" DocType="" InsUser="admin" InsTime="20120910175739" ModUser="rtirabassi" ModTime="20120925145347"?>
     <?xw-crc key32=e324f581-406521b5?>

  </scheda_conservatore>
```

---

Ok, now the problem is assuming another aspect. Probably I have to "close" this and pass to another quiestion.

XPath, on the originale (wider) XML document, is correct and now I see where the problem is but have no idea about how to solve it.

- If I execute just once the XPath expression onto the XML document, I HAVE THE EXPECTED RESULT;
- If I execute a pretty large sequence of XPath onto the same XML document, complex XPaths (containing condition concerning attribute values) fails (those ones and only those);

So I took a look on how we implemented the XPath evaluation and find that the XPathContext saw never freed. So I changed the code in order to free the context after each XPath evaluation and create a new one everytime but... nothing changes.

Any Idea?

Comment: Yes, as I told, the same XML document, treated with an XPath resolver (jEdit with appropriate PlugIn), gives a valid result, that means, the first XPath expression that give me no valid result in a C++ programm give a valid in other scenarios (PHP, Java...)

Comment: Can you post the full `lower_list` tag XML (including attributes and content) which you're matching against?

Comment: Are there namespaces in your document?

Comment: You say: the first XPath expression that give me no valid result in a C++ programm give a valid in other scenarios (PHP, Java...). So it seems there's a bug in your XPath processor.

Comment: Hem... My XPath processor is from libmxl2, if it's bugged what shall I do?
More: the problem arises if I test it using the code compiled in Windows and Linux too so both lixml2 fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath works correctly. You are looking for `@id='037006-001-2012-ri002` and the attribute value is `037006-001-2012-ri001`. After changing xml to `ri002` it matches, libxml returns the correct nodesetval.

In case it does not really resolve the problem: maybe `id` attribute is treated in a special way? Try changing it to `idx`. See [Java XML DOM: how are id Attributes special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423430/java-xml-dom-how-are-id-attributes-special)

Comment: Confirmed the same thing, example XML has ri001 and xpaths specify ri002.  Changing xpaths to ri002 has all expressions mentioned in the question return results.

Comment: My fault: the original XML file was over 150KB and I just can't add it to the original message (max amount of chars is 30000).
During cut & past I removed the elements matching with the sample I did before.
I'll try to cut it differently.
Pay attention: I already know that the XPath il correct (according to the content of the XML), I only say, as Michale Key did, that C implementation of libxml2 (both Win and Linux) fails resolving this XPath, while the same, in Java, in PHP and other, works properly.

Comment: Gate, So you suggest that it fails on a big file and passes on a small one? Because we tried it on a small file (of yours). So try dividing your 150KB until you find a smallest offending example to submit a bug report to libxml. Is your app failing on a small example, that you posted? So I would rather search for a bug in your app. When I'm home I'll attach a small c prog that succeeded with your xpath expression on your (corrected ri001->ri002) file.

Comment: Here's the topic. No matter how big or small the file is, but if I evaluate a wide list of XPaths, when the one containing condition on attributes is tested it fails.
If I skip all previous test and just evaluate that path, the result is correct so...
...there must be something in the way the evaluation method is used in a massive way.
Took a look to XPath context, creating as new each time, but with no result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, find the question.
Sorry for this false alarm. libxml2 works properly but there were changes into the XML document, during a cycle of XPath evaluations, that changed the scenario causing me to believe the XPath processor was failing.
The deep debugging session showed us that something else was wrong and only he XPath expression having a condition on an attribute (but not the last condition) failed. This drove us to the solution. 
My fault. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, I flagged the question to close/delete, as the title question doesn't hold true. Anyway I guess we helped you and probably you could accept the answer "XPath works correctly".

Comment: I think I MUST accept a valid answer since the fault is all mine (of a colleague of mine, indeed) and the XPath is working properly.

Comment: Don't worry :) I'm glad you solved the problem and that you explained all to us. Thanks!