# XML dig sig error after upgrade to java7u25

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature

I have a Java application for signing XML documents. After upgrading Java to the latest version (Java7u25) it stops working. I get the following error:

```
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException:
javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: 
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException:
Cannot resolve element with ID ...
```

Reverting back to java7u21 solves the problem. Is there any change in the XML Dig Sig API that causes this error?

Comment: Hi Kresok & welcome to stackoverflow. I've voted up, but please report the complete stacktrace, and try to format the stacktrace as code (using the `{}` button).

Comment: I finally found a workaround for this new Java restriction... see below

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Same problem here. Seems to be a bug inside the JVM due to an evolution.

I've traked it down to `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverFragment`

In java 7u21 & before :

```
91: // Element selectedElem = doc.getElementById(id);
92: selectedElem = IdResolver.getElementById(doc, id);
```

In java 7u25 :

```
87: selectedElem = doc.getElementById(id);
    //...
93: if (secureValidation) {
```

`secureValidation` refers to java 7u25 evolution on XML Sig validation (see [changelog](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html#sec-val)) so they must have <strike>broken</strike> **changed something else** while working on this evolution.

We've worked around this issue by providing a custom `javax.xml.crypto.URIDereferencer` to `javax.xml.crypto.dom.DOMCryptoContext.setURIDereferencer(URIDereferencer)` which is able to resolve node which are not yet in the DOM document tree (fragments in XMLObject).

<strike>I'm reporting this to Oracle right now, I'll update the answer with the bug id.</strike>

---

**EDIT :** found this in [apache SVN](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/santuario/xml-security-java/branches/1.5.x-fixes/src/main/java/org/apache/xml/security/utils/resolver/implementations/ResolverFragment.java?r1=1213661&r2=1231033&pathrev=1493772&diff_format=h)

---

**Edit 2 :** Thanks to [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SANTUARIO-312) I've understood that this was an evolution in XML "Id" attributes handling.

Previous versions of java/JSR-105/SANTUARIO used to be very tolerant on "Id" attributes used in `document.getElementById(...)` but this new version requires an attribute that is identified as **ID** XML speaking. I mean that naming the attribute "Id" or "ID" is not sufficient anymore, you need to get it marked as ID, **eventually by an XSD/DTD schema validation.**

**Unfortunalty, I'm following a schema that is not valid and therefore not parsable by Java.**

If you are in the same situation see my solution below. Otherwise, if you're XML document does have a valid schema, have a look at @sherb solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/17437919/233906

## Solution

Fortunately, you can *tag* an attribute as an ID using methods like [`Element.setIdAttributeNode(org.w3c.dom.Attr,boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setIdAttributeNode%28org.w3c.dom.Attr,%20boolean%29).

Combining with a little XPath like `descendant-or-self::*/@Id` to fetch `Attr` "Id" nodes plus a little Java `((Element)attr.getOwnerElement()).setIdAttributeNode(attr,true)` should get you out of trouble.

**But be carefull :** `setIdAttributeXXX()` is valid only for the current document & node. If you `clone`/`adopt`/`import` you need to do a `setIdAttributeXXX()` on the new nodes of each DOM tree

Comment: Thanks Element.setIdAttribute(...) worked for me since I'm not dealing with any schema validation.

Comment: Hi @RajatNigam 7u55 is outdated (as the [whole 7 branch](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html)) you should not use it anymore and switch to Java 8. Have you tried my solution or [sherb's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17437919/233906) ?

Comment: with the solution my digest is getting changed

Comment: It can occur if you have overlapping ID with the generator using one node and the validator another. Have you tried dumping the canonized XML on both side (just before hash computation). I used to do this when stuck by strange hash changes

Answer (score 11):

I also found the responses to this question quite helpful, but my solution was a bit different. I'm working with OpenSAML 2.6.0, and assigning a schema to the DocumentBuilderFactory just before parsing the incoming document resolved the `ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID...` exception by properly marking the ID attributes. Here's an example:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(assertion.getBytes());       
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new URL("http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd"));
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setSchema(schema);
Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(in);
```

Comment: Excellent and elegant solution

Comment: For SAML, as with most applications, this is definitely the way to go: you don't mess with the DOM after loading it, and you make sure that the document is loaded according to the Schema.

Comment: I tried this, but the parsing of the SAML response was really slow (30sec on OpenJDK 6b32 and Oracle JDK 8u25). The best I found is to use **DOMValidateContext.setIdAttributeNS(...)**.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz You're right. I had to do it the ugly way because I had no valid schema (nor time to figure out how to refactor it correctly). This might not be clear enough in my answer, I'll edit it to point sherb's one in case someone does have a valid schema.

Comment: I think the proper way to deal with this is using the Schema (XSD) of the XML in question. The answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365111/577769 from SeppSeppler) made me think that, it is not enough to have a ID attribute at the XML, we have to have an XSD of this same XML saying the this ID attribute is the type of xsd:ID, and not xsd:string. After doing this, informing the proper XSD of the XML in the DocumentBuilderFactory, everything starts working well. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same probleme with the code :

```
element.setAttributeNS(null, "Id", elementID);
```

**FIX :**  specify id

```
element.setAttributeNS(null, "Id", elementID);
Attr idAttr = element.getAttributeNode("Id");
element.setIdAttributeNode(idAttr, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

i faced the same issue and also tracked it down to the code snippets mentioned by Cerber.
I'm curious whether this is a bug or a change made on purpose.

With the information given in this thread 
[Java XML DOM: how are id Attributes special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423430/java-xml-dom-how-are-id-attributes-special)
i was able to get things back to work again.

In a nutshell the 'ID' attribute has to be of type 'xs:ID' (and not e.g. 'xs:string') for the Dereferencer to find it. Also note that depending on your use of a DocumentBuilderFactory the XML schema must be set.

Comment: Thanks SeppSeppler : I had missed this answer it could have helped me

Comment: Thanks SeepSeppeler, after creating the XSD (and loading it at the DocumentBuilderFactory) of my XML, I did not have this problem anymore, either Signing the XML, or Checking the Signing of the same XML.

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
dsObjectChild.setAttribute("Id", "My-id-value");
```

Change it to

```
dsObjectChild.setAttribute("Id", "My-id-value");
dsObjectChild.setIdAttribute("Id", true);
```

It is working with java 1.7.0_45

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue only when ID is set with random UUID [`guidForSignature ="_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();`] and when there are concurrent requests triggered at run time(Java 1.8).

I have tried setting the ID attribute like below which didn't help me. However, setting the ID attribute to constant ID value for all the requests resolved the issue.

```
Element element1= doc.getDocumentElement().setIdAttribute("ID", true);
```

OR

```
Element e1 =(Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("Assertion").item(0);
e1.setIdAttribute("ID", true);
```