# Secure validation error while signing docx file with apache poi

Tags: java, exception, ms-office, apache-poi, digital-signature

I am trying to sign a docx file via the apache poi api. I found example given in the SignatureInfo class [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/dsig/SignatureInfo.html). Here is the code:

```
OPCPackage pgk = OPCPackage
                .open("D:/Users/Desktop/demo.docx", PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
        SignatureConfig signatureConfig = new SignatureConfig();
        signatureConfig.setKey(certificationChain.privateKeyAndCertChain.privateKey);
        signatureConfig.setSigningCertificateChain(Collections.singletonList(certificate));
        signatureConfig.setDigestAlgo(HashAlgorithm.sha1);
        signatureConfig.setOpcPackage(pgk);

        SignatureInfo si = new SignatureInfo();
        si.setSignatureConfig(signatureConfig);
        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        DigestInfo digestInfo = si.preSign(document, null);
        byte[] signatureValue = si.signDigest(digestInfo.digestValue);


        si.postSign(document, signatureValue);
        boolean b = si.verifySignature();
        assert (b);
        pgk.close();
```

But when I run it I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID idSignedProperties
at org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverFragment.engineResolve(ResolverFragment.java:86)
at org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.resolve(ResourceResolver.java:279)
at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(DOMURIDereferencer.java:115)
```

I searched about that error and I understood a lot from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331187/xml-dig-sig-error-after-upgrade-to-java7u25). There are given solutions to the problem, which is caused by the new  [secureValidation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html#sec-val) property. 
BUT .. I do not have access to the classes in the api so the solutions are useless for me.

Any ideas how to fix this problem with apache poi?

Comment: Does the same code work on a very simple `.docx` file? Does it work if you use Java 6 rather than Java 7?