# Xml id attribute to work with Java's getElementById?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have an xml document being parsed in Java as a w3c document.
In my xml, i have many elements of the same name, e.g `<item ..... />`, each one with unique attribute's value, e.g `<item name="a" .... />`.
I want in java to do:

```
doc.getElementById("a")
```

in order to get that specific item I have there with that name.
How can I tell java to use 'name' as the id?
Or, alternately, How can I fetch that specific item in least complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOM is not the best API to easily query your document and get back found elements. Learn XPath, which is a more appropriate API, or iterate through the tree of elements by yourself.

`getElementById()` will only return the element which has the given `id` attribute (edit: marked as such in the document DTD or schema). It can't find by `name` attribute.

See [Java XML DOM: how are id Attributes special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423430/java-xml-dom-how-are-id-attributes-special) for details.

Comment: I tried the following XML: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><item id="a">......</item></root>` and I still get null. Why is that?

Comment: Now I'm confused. I sincerely thought id was de facto the ID element, but the javadoc indicates that the attribute is only considered as an ID attribute if it's declared as such (in the DTD or schema, I presume). See http://webdesign.about.com/od/xml/a/aa061801a.htm for example. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423430/java-xml-dom-how-are-id-attributes-special

Comment: Thanks. it did get me somewhere to start with. However, seems annoying, as once I declare a dtd schema, It implies that any attribute I didnt declare in the schema, is invalid and shouldnt be there

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a DTD that defines your attribute as being of type `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, To make a complete answer, I had to use DTD schemas like everyone stated.
Since my needs are quite simple, I added it in embedded in my xml the  following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
    <!ATTLIST item 
        name ID #REQUIRED
        >
]>
<root> .... </root>
```

The only important thing left to know is that once you declare the ATTLIST, I have to declare all of the rest of my attributes, therefore, you need to add IMPLIED:

```
some-attribute CDATA #IMPLIED
```

It says that some-attribute contains some data (can use also PCDATA for parsed cdata), and is implied, which means, it can be there or it cannot. doesnt matter.

So eventually, it'll look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
    <!ATTLIST item 
        name ID #REQUIRED
        some-attribute CDATA #IMPLIED
        >
]>
<root> .... </root>
```

And from Java side, Just use it blindly, e.g `getElementById("some-name")`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work by itself. I think we also need to define the element names.

Comment: @HRJ for me it worked flawlessly. did you use the dtd schema embedded within the xml or did you place it in a different file? If the first, it should work as I wrote and if the latter then maybe you need to "import" it. assuming both xml and dtd are in the same folder, try `<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "mySchema.dtd">` at top of the xml file

Comment: I embedded it. The error I got was (to paraphrase): `html, body, p,  elements not defined` Can you please quote the exact DTD that needs to be added for an HTML/XHTML/XML doc?

Comment: @HRJ My Xml looks the following way `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "DefaultItemsDefinitions.dtd"><root><item name="a" type="1"/></root>`
My dtd schema is `<!ATTLIST item 
 name ID #REQUIRED
 type (string|link) "string"
>` Both are in the same folder and that allows me to do `getElementById(..)` for what specified in my .dtd schema as `ID`. You can, if you prefer, replace the `<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM ...>` with the actual content of the dtd schema, that will be the same. for me, I use the same schema several times, so Importing it is more convenient and modular

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `doc.getElementById("a")` work you need to change your XML to `<item id="a" name="a" .... />`

If you can't change the XML, you could use XPath to retrieve this element.

Comment: That I already tried, however it returns null

Comment: You added an id attribute to the item tag and the getElementById method returns null ?

Comment: Yes, I really dont know why. See the answer to JB Nizet, I posted there the xml.

Comment: As JB Nizet suggested maybe your id attribute is not considered as a proper ID. What parser do you use ?

Comment: Yes, I added a small schema describing only my attributes.