# Why does getElementById is not working for me? In Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to get an element by id in Java with Document object (`org.w3c.dom.Document`), but when I use the function `getElementById(elementId)` is returning a null. The `Document` Object is creating Ok, because I use `getElementByTags` and works fine.

My code in Java:

```
DocumentBuilder dbRespuesta0 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document docRespuesta0 = dbRespuesta0.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(context.getProperty("XML").toString())));
Element e = (Element) docRespuesta0.getElementById("ID_X");
```

The structure of my XML

```
<RESULT>
    <TAG1 ID="A">
        
    </TAG1>
    <TAG1 ID="B">
       
    </TAG1>
    <TAG2 DIM="30" ID="C" SIZE="2">
        
    </TAG2>
    <TAG2 DIM="300" ID="ID_X" SIZE="2">
        <TAG3 NUM="1">
            
        </TAG3>
        <TAG3 NUM="2">
           
        </TAG3>
    </TAG2>
</RESULT>
```

When I print the element e, I watch a null. I hope to getting in the element e, the next XML:

```
<TAG2 DIM="300" ID="ID_X" SIZE="2">
    <TAG3 NUM="1">

    </TAG3>
    <TAG3 NUM="2">

    </TAG3>
</TAG2>
```

Comment: getElemenyById is looking for an attribute of the type ID not the value "ID".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setSchema(schema)` to define a dom-schema that explains to the model that the attribute `ID` is in fact the ID of the node.

From the javadoc of `org.w3c.dom.Document` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementById(java.lang.String))

> Element getElementById(String elementId)
>
> Returns the Element that has an ID attribute with the given value. If
> no such element exists, this returns null . If more than one element
> has an ID attribute with that value, what is returned is undefined.
> **The DOM implementation is expected to use the attribute Attr.isId to
> determine if an attribute is of type ID.**
>
> **Note: Attributes with the name "ID" or "id" are not of type ID unless
> so defined.**

Note the last two (highlighted) lines!

An attribute must explicitly be defined as ID, and not just be named "ID".

This question/answer gives a detailed explanation and should help you out:
[Java XML DOM: how are id Attributes special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423430/java-xml-dom-how-are-id-attributes-special)